# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.10 on MSI laptop - SSDs and HDD not found in SATA RAID Mode

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, raid

I've recently bought an MSI laptop (GT73VR 6RE) laptop and while it's great in Windows 10, I'm trying to dual-boot it with a Linux distro (Ubuntu primarily, although I've tried Linux Mint too).

I created a bootable LiveUSB of Ubuntu 16.10, set the USB drive to boot before the RAID array in the UEFI menu. I get to the grub boot menu where I can either "Install Ubuntu" or "Try without installing", but when I get into Ubuntu installer/desktop, the RAID'd SSDs and non-RAID HDD cannot be seen in GParted, fdisk or lsblk (although I can see the RAID controller listed with "lspci -nnk", which shows as using AHCI drivers, which is a bit confusing as I've left RAID set in UEFI).

I've tried editing the grub boot parameters with the addition of "nomodeset idle=nomwait acpi_osi=Linux nvme_load=YES mdadm=true" but all to no avail. I've also disabled FastBoot, SecureBoot and various Virtualisation/CPU-type parameters people have said may need to be disabled in UEFI.

The only success I've had is when changing from RAID to AHCI in the UEFI screens... the SSDs and HDD all then appear within Ubuntu but the RAID configuration is disabled, so I'd no longer be able to get into Windows.

Is there a way of seeing the (Intel RST) RAID setup within Ubuntu so the two operating systems can be dual-booted?

Comment: I *believe* that the answer is no, Ubuntu desktop won't install with RAID in place. Let the other experts chime in on that. It would be interesting to see if `Ubuntu Server` Live DVD/USB would see the RAID. You could always install `ubuntu-desktop` later.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen the server suggestion somewhere else, will give it a try later this week and see what happens

Comment: Tried a Server installation but basically the same thing - only time the drives can be seen (SSDs or HDD) is when the "SATA Mode" in the UEFI menu is set to AHCI instead of RAID.

Comment: I've heard that some recent Lenovo laptops are also coming with their single-drive boot drive configured in a pseudo-RAID configuration, and Ubuntu can't be installed there either. I heard that Lenovo put out a firmware/BIOS patch to "fix" the problem. The pseudo-RAID was supposedly to assure that only Microsoft OS's could be installed.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that while searching, hoping MSI haven't done the same kind of thing (however unintentional). Have updated to the latest BIOS/UEFI version at least just in case, but no difference so far. Oh well, maybe need to decide whether to drop the RAID configuration, wait to see if future updates permit the dual-boot install or look at VM'ing Ubuntu within Windows (which I don't particularly want to do, but may be the way it ends up going,at least in the near-term)